# tensorflow applying tf.boolean_mask

Tags: tensorflow

```
        # Select samples from same class
        same_match = tf.equal(match_ids, match_id)
        same_class = tf.equal(class_ids, class_id)

        positive = tf.logical_and(same_match, same_class)
        negative = tf.logical_not(positive)

        samples_pos = tf.boolean_mask(f_anchor, positive)
        samples_neg = tf.boolean_mask(f_anchor, negative)
```

This code gives the following error:

> ValueError: Shapes (?, 32) and (?, 1) are incompatible

for this line:

> line 138, in body
>       samples_pos = tf.boolean_mask(f_anchor, positive)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py",
>   line 1157, in boolean_mask
>       shape_tensor[:ndims_mask].assert_is_compatible_with(shape_mask)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py",
>   line 753, in assert_is_compatible_with
>       raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other)) ValueError: Shapes (?, 32) and (?, 1) are incompatible

so I try to solve it with tf.squeeze:

```
# Select samples from same class
same_match = tf.equal(match_ids, match_id)
same_class = tf.equal(class_ids, class_id)

positive = tf.logical_and(same_match, same_class)
negative = tf.logical_not(positive)

samples_pos = tf.boolean_mask(f_anchor, tf.squeeze(positive))
samples_neg = tf.boolean_mask(f_anchor, tf.squeeze(negative))
```

But then the output is

> File "triplet.py", line 138, in body
>       samples_pos = tf.boolean_mask(f_anchor, tf.squeeze(positive))   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py",
>   line 1155, in boolean_mask
>       "Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions" ValueError: Number of mask dimensions must be specified,
>   even if some dimensions are None.  E.g. shape=[None] is ok, but
>   shape=None is not.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Could you pls post a code that I can regenerate in my PC. Otherwise will be very hard to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
positive = tf.squeeze(positive)
negative = tf.squeeze(negative)
positive.set_shape([None])
negative.set_shape([None])
```

This seems to work